Importing login of users/tests module to another application/tests not working in Django
I'm trying to avoid code duplication so I want to import login from users/test to the ordering/test where I need to test different views that have @login_required.
users/test.py
User = get_user_model()

class UserBaseTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='testuser', 
            password='testpass', 
            email='test@gmail.com', 
            phone_number='3401234567'
        )

    def test_login(self):
        logged_in = self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testpass')
        self.assertTrue(logged_in, "Login failed in UserBaseTest")

ordering/test.py
class OrderTest(UserBaseTest): 
    def test_view(self):
        self.test_login()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('homepage'), follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(response, self.order_url)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'ordering/ordering.html')

If I ran py manage.py test users no errors and no failures were elevated, but with py manage.py test ordering it gave me:
self.assertTrue(logged_in, "Login failed in UserBaseTest")
AssertionError: False is not true : Login failed in UserBaseTest


Did you override setUp in the OrderTest?

@willeM_VanOnsem with def setUp(self): super().setUp() ? yes, i did it, but nothing changed
